# Python: Run all iterations, then continue with new tasks inside the loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I wonder if there is any convenient way to run all iterations in a while loop to a certain row in the loop. I would use this to then compare the results of every iteration, and move along based on the result.

This is the code I have so far:

```
source = requests.get('https://website.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
pm = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-item span3')

antal_pm = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d={}

for x in antal_pm:
    senaste = pm[x]
    senaste_text = senaste.text
    d["senaste_text{0}".format(x)] = senaste_text
    url_link = senaste.find('a').get('href')
    source = requests.get(url_link).text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    twitter_url = soup1.find('a', class_='twitter social-link').get('href')
    source1 = requests.get(twitter_url).text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source1, 'lxml')
    twitter_grund = soup2.find('textarea').text
    url_link_formaterad = re.search('com/se/(.+?)/r/', url_link).group(1)
    d["ulf{0}".format(x)] = url_link_formaterad
    matches_grund = next((x for x in bolag if x in senaste_text), 'URL-triggad')
    d["match{0}".format(x)] = matches_grund
    twitter_p = twitter_grund[:-18] + ("#hashtag") + (" #anotherhashtag") + " " + (T1 if B1 in matches_grund else '') + (T2 if B2 in matches_grund else '') + (T3 if B3 in matches_grund else '') + (T4 if B4 in matches_grund else '') + (T5 if B5 in matches_grund else '') + (T6 if B6 in matches_grund else '') + (T7 if B7 in matches_grund else '') + (T8 if B8 in matches_grund else '') + (T9 if B9 in matches_grund else '') + (T10 if B10 in matches_grund else '') + (T11 if B11 in matches_grund else '') + (T12 if B12 in matches_grund else '') + (T13 if B13 in matches_grund else '') + (T14 if B14 in matches_grund else '') + (T15 if B15 in matches_grund else '') + (T16 if B16 in matches_grund else '') + (T17 if B17 in matches_grund else '') + (T18 if B18 in matches_grund else '') + (T19 if B19 in matches_grund else '') + (T20 if B20 in matches_grund else '') + (T21 if B21 in matches_grund else '') + (T22 if B22 in matches_grund else '') + (T23 if B23 in matches_grund else '') + (T24 if B24 in matches_grund else '') + (T25 if B25 in matches_grund else '') + (T26 if B26 in matches_grund else '') + (T27 if B27 in matches_grund else '') + (T28 if B28 in matches_grund else '') + (T29 if B29 in matches_grund else '') + (T30 if B30 in matches_grund else '') + (T31 if B31 in matches_grund else '') + (T32 if B32 in matches_grund else '') + (T33 if B33 in matches_grund else '') + (T34 if B34 in matches_grund else '') + (T35 if B35 in matches_grund else '') + (T36 if B36 in matches_grund else '') + (T37 if B37 in matches_grund else '') + (T38 if B38 in matches_grund else '') + (T39 if B39 in matches_grund else '')# + (T40 if B40 in matches1 else '')# + (T41 if B41 in matches1 else '') + (T42 if B42 in matches1 else '') + (T43 if B43 in matches1 else '') + (T44 if B44 in matches1 else '') + (T45 if B45 in matches1 else '') + (T46 if B46 in matches1 else '') + (T47 if B47 in matches1 else '') + (T48 if B48 in matches1 else '') + (T49 if B49 in matches1 else '') + (T50 if B50 in matches1 else '') + (T51 if B51 in matches1 else '') + (T52 if B52 in matches1 else '') + (T53 if B53 in matches1 else '') + (T54 if B54 in matches1 else '') + (T55 if B55 in matches1 else '') + (T56 if B56 in matches1 else '') + (T57 if B57 in matches1 else '') + (T58 if B58 in matches1 else '') + (T59 if B59 in matches1 else '') + (T60 if B60 in matches1 else '') + (T61 if B61 in matches1 else '') + (T62 if B62 in matches1 else '') + (T63 if B63 in matches1 else '') + (T64 if B64 in matches1 else '') + (T65 if B65 in matches1 else '') + (T66 if B66 in matches1 else '') + (T67 if B67 in matches1 else '') + (T68 if B68 in matches1 else '') + (T69 if B69 in matches1 else '') + (T70 if B70 in matches1 else '') + (T71 if B71 in matches1 else '') + (T72 if B72 in matches1 else '') + (T73 if B73 in matches1 else '') + (T74 if B74 in matches1 else '') + (T75 if B75 in matches1 else '')
    d["twitter_post{0}".format(x)] = twitter_p
    title_base = re.search('(.+?) https://', twitter_p).group(1)[:100]
    d["title{0}".format(x)] = title_base
```

I would like to run all 10 iterations through this block of code and then be able to summerize the results and move on based on it.

An example on how the loop could continue:

``````
    all_titles = d[title0] + " " + d[title1] + " " + d[title2] + " " + d[title3] + " " + d[title4]

    if matches_grund in all_titles:
        print("found")
        post_through_api()
`````Note that ```` matches_grund ```` will be different for each iteration. Thanks in advance!
``````

Comment: Please make your question Minimal and Reproducible (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it stands there is way too much that is irrelevant here. Try to boil it down to the core of what you are asking. Remove the stuff that is specific to your case (BeautifulSourp, twitter urls etc.) and create a generic example instead. You are much more likely to get help from the community then

Comment: This question is still vague. What is the criterion? Are iterations fixed sized? What have you done so far?

Comment: You may want to read about [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. Also - totally unrelated but anyway - you may want to learn about Python string formatting operations and the `str.join()` method.